# how to query only dd/MM part of sql date

Tags: sql, database

Hi I would like to query some data from a sql database for birthdays. I only want to find a record that matches dd/MM , how can I do this? The DOB is in the format of this: YYYY-MM-dd 00:00:00.000

```
 sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM [myDb].[dbo].[TblPeople] 
        WHERE txtLeavingDate IS NULL 
          AND intNCYear Between'7' AND '13' 
          AND txtDOB like'07/27'";
```

Comment: Each database engine uses slightly different logic.  This appears to be SQL server can you confirm what engine and version you are using? and confirm what datatype DOB is the format simply means it could be varchar or it could be datetime or something else... Just want all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you can use [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql):

```
select *
from [myDb].[dbo].[TblPeople]
where txtLeavingDate is null
    and intNCYear between 7 and 13
    and datepart(day, txtDOB) = 27
    and datepart(month, txtDOB) = 07
;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple enough to use the `year()` and month()` functions.  More importantly, you need to pay attention to the use of single quotes.  Do not use single quotes on *numbers*, only for date and string constants:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [myDb].[dbo].[TblPeople] 
WHERE txtLeavingDate IS NULL AND
       intNCYear Between 7 AND 13 AND
       month(txtDOB) = 7 AND
       day(txtDOB) = 27;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select *from [myDb].[dbo].[TblPeople]where txtLeavingDate is null and intNCYear between 7 and 13
and datepart(day, txtDOB) = 27
and datepart(month, txtDOB) = 07
```

both the above answers were correct, thanks for the advice!